# Azure Synapse recursive CTE alternative for flatten hierarchy

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-synapse

I am facing following challenge: I would like to flatten a parent child hierarchy in a way that I have per row the child + any parent of the upper levels

**Source data**

| Child | Parent |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| B | C |
| D | E |
| X | Y |
| Y | Z |

**Whished result**

| Child | Any Parent |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| A | C |
| A | D |
| A | E |
| B | C |
| B | D |
| B | E |
| C | D |
| C | E |
| D | E |
| X | Y |
| X | Z |
| Y | Z |

There is no information about levels and there is not a distinct "Top parent". It is a unbalanced tree and there might be multiple "Top 1 parents" with different childs.

I know this should normally be done via a recursive CTE, but since this is not supported in Azure Synapse I am searching for a smart loop statement to solve this puzzle. Performance is not the priority since it is in a DWH context with not that much data.

Really appreciate any smart hints or solutions

Tried several recursive CTE solutions for that which are unfortunately all not supported in Synapse

Comment: I'm not familiarized with `azure-synapse` Can you run standard tsql? or do you need a python script for this task?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67065509/1527504

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the limitations are with Azure Synapse but try this a..

It's won't win any awards for elegance but does the job. I corrected what I assumed to be a missing record in your sample data too (C, D) based on your expected output.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(Child varchar(10), Parent varchar(10))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'E'), ('X', 'Y'), ('Y', 'Z')

DECLARE @Items TABLE (Item varchar(10), Done INT)
DECLARE @Results TABLE(Child varchar(10), Parent varchar(10))
DECLARE @p varchar(10)
DECLARE @curItem varchar(10)

INSERT INTO @Items (item)
    SELECT DISTINCT Child FROM @t 
    UNION 
    SELECT DISTINCT Parent FROM @t 

SET @curItem = (SELECT TOP 1 Item FROM @Items WHERE Done IS NULL)

WHILE @curItem IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN 

        SELECT @p = Parent FROM @t  WHERE Child = @curItem

        WHILE @p IS NOT NULL 
            BEGIN 
                INSERT INTO @Results
                    SELECT @curItem, Parent FROM @t WHERE Parent = @p 

                SET @p = (SELECT Parent FROM @t  WHERE Child = @p)

            END

        UPDATE @Items SET Done = 1 WHERE Item = @curItem
        SET @curItem = (SELECT TOP 1 Item FROM @Items WHERE Done IS NULL)
    END 

SELECT * FROM @Results
```

I tested this and it does work, tried to stick on sql fiddle but it would not run on there for some rerason.

Anyway,

Here's the results

[image]